# How to deal with cascading priority in CSS?

Tags: css

Let's say I have links looking like buttons all over my app. They are orange, unless they are "disabled" (having no `href`):

```css
a.button {
    background-color: orange;
}

a.button:not([href]) {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Now, I'm not sure how to allow certain buttons look different in their context, but keep the disabled ones as they were. Let's say I need the "buttons" inside my `<footer>` to be green, or - as usual - grey if disabled:

```css
footer a.button {
    background-color: green;
}
```

The problem is that this rule has higher priority, as it's more specific. How can I allow disabled buttons in the footer to still be grey without repeating my code? I know I can use `!important`, but please assume that my real-life example is more complex and I want to avoid using it.

Comment: You could specify the opposite state `a.button[href]` so that the rules don't clash or use a preprocessor like Sass to extend a base class.

Comment: That opposite state means repeating the code already. CSS gets dirty quickly when trying to do that this way, with lots and lots of repeated logic. Managing these states later is a nightmare.

Comment: I think something like what @IronMan suggests would work - `footer a.button[href]` would not override your `a.button:not([href])` rule set, since they wouldn't match the same elements. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0dkowbct/

Comment: Like I said, it's against the DRY principle. My rule of the lack of href attribute behaving like disabled should be defined once, not twice. I can later decide to make this rule different and I would need to remember all places where I defined it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're meaning, there - your footer rule (in this example) is not the same as the "generic" rule.

Comment: If what you're after is "the styles change depending on the parent element," that's not possible - there's no parent selector in CSS (yet).

Comment: It doesn't help your question that the specificity presumption is incorrect. `footer a.button` has a lower specificity than `a.button:not([href])` and so won't override it.

Comment: @Alohci well yeah, that's the point. CSS uses its own specifity engine, despite what is logical for my app.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS variables. You define the default value and you simply set the variable to define a new one.

```css
a.button {
  background-color: var(--main, orange);
}

a.button:not([href]) {
  background-color: var(--disable, grey);
}

footer#foo a.button { /*I am adding an ID to make it really more specific*/
  --main: green;
}
```

```html
<a class="button">a link</a>
<a href="" class="button">a link</a>

<footer id="foo">
  <a class="button">a link</a>
  <a href="" class="button">a link</a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://qnimate.com/dive-into-css-specificity/ to see a full list of CSS specificity.

Assuming you have more than one `a.button` in your footer, we'll skip using a plain id selector. You could pair an id and attribute selector, using the title attribute to identify all disabled "buttons":

index.html

```
<a class="button">a link</a>
<a href="" class="button">a link</a>

<footer id="foo">
  <a class="button" title="disabled">a link</a>
  <a href="" class="button" title="disabled">a link</a>
</footer>
```

and styles.css

```
#foo a[title="disabled"] {
     color: green;
}
```

Comment: Using `title` to identify element as disabled? You know that the `title` attribute appears as a tooltip when you hover over the element?